# AngularJS datalist pagination / infinity scroll on datalist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, infinite-loop, infinite-scroll

I am using a `datalist` that loads data from a restful API, I want to add pagination in my `datalist`, I am using AngularJS:

```
    <label>Query:</label>
    <input list="data">
</div>

<datalist id="data">
    <option ng-repeat="data in queries" value="{{data.name}}">
    </option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a external module like [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) to call a function when your user is near the bottom of the page. This function should load the next load of objects from your API and add it to your `queries` array. It will automatically expend the list with the new content.

Comment: yes , now i figure out another problem , i will be using ie 8 so i cannot use datalist so can i use this external module for input text?

Answer (score 0):

i did it using jquery -- autocomplete (by writing own directive in angular js)
My directive function looks like :

```
myModule.directive("autoCompletequery",function(queryService){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, element) {

            element.autocomplete({

                source: queryService.getQueries()

            });
```

Get Queries gets the data from factory.

```
<label>Query:</label>
        <input  ng-model="query" placeholder="search for query" auto-completequery/>
        Query = {{query}}
```